# Why I am suddenly getting a "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error when introducing properties type hints?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, php-7, type-hinting, php-7.4

I have updated my class definitions to make use of the newly introduced property type hints, like this:

```php
class Foo {

    private int $id;
    private ?string $val;
    private DateTimeInterface $createdAt;
    private ?DateTimeInterface $updatedAt;

    public function __construct(int $id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    public function getId(): int { return $this->id; }
    public function getVal(): ?string { return $this->val; }
    public function getCreatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface { return $this->createdAt; }
    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface { return $this->updatedAt; }

    public function setVal(?string $val) { $this->val = $val; }
    public function setCreatedAt(DateTimeInterface $date) { $this->createdAt = $date; }
    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTimeInterface $date) { $this->updatedAt = $date; }
}
```

But when trying to save my entity on Doctrine I am getting an error saying:

> Typed property must not be accessed before initialization

This not only happens with `$id` or `$createdAt`, but also happen with `$value` or `$updatedAt`, which are nullable properties.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Since PHP 7.4 introduces type-hinting for properties, it is particularly important to provide valid values for all properties, so that all properties have values that match their declared types.

A property that has never been assigned doesn't have a `null` value, but it is in an `undefined` state, **which will never match any declared type**. `undefined !== null`.

For the code above, if you did:

```
$f = new Foo(1);
$f->getVal();
```

You would get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property Foo::$val must not be accessed before initialization

Since `$val` is neither `string` nor `null` when accessing it.

The way to get around this is to assign values to all your properties that match the declared types. You can do this either as default values for the property or during construction, depending on your preference and the type of the property.

For example, for the above one could do:

```php
class Foo {

    private int $id;
    private ?string $val = null; // <-- declaring default null value for the property
    private Collection $collection;
    private DateTimeInterface $createdAt;
    private ?DateTimeInterface $updatedAt;

    public function __construct(int $id) {
        // and on the constructor we set the default values for all the other 
        // properties, so now the instance is on a valid state
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->createdAt = new DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTimeImmutable();

        $this->collection = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Now all properties would have a **valid** value and the instance would be on a valid state.

This can hit particularly often when you are relying on values that come from the DB for entity values. E.g. auto-generated IDs, or creation and/or updated values; which often are left as a DB concern.

For auto-generated IDs, [the recommended way forward](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7944#issuecomment-561945539) is to change the type declaration to:

```
private ?int $id = null
```

For all the rest, just choose an appropriate value for the property's type.

Comment: In other words, there is **null safety** for the type-hinted class members since PHP 7.4.

Comment: You can also check if properties are initialized safely using isset() if needed, to avoid initialising e.g. with null

Answer (score 45):

For nullable typed properties you need to use syntax

`private ?string $val = null;`

otherwise it throws a fatal error.

Since this concept leads to unnecessary fatal errors, I have created a bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79620 - with no success, but at least I tried...

Comment: a) That's already covered in the other answer. b) That's not a bug. That's by (good) design. If a property may hold a `null` besides a defined type, you want to be explicit about it. I would expect such a report to be declined out of hand.

Comment: Straight forward answer. Well done!