# problem to acces to a property of a child with the function of the parent in php 8.x

Tags: php, inheritance, php-8

I'm makin a framework to make my own server, to do this i had implemented many classes, one of this is a class named model who is a generic parent class that suports other specific models.
this is the construction of the class model:

```
namespace app\core;
use app\models\RegisterModel;
abstract class Model
{ 

  /*just definition of generic properties and rules to the model*/


  public array $errors = [];
  public const RULE_REQUIRED = 'required';
  public const RULE_EMAIL = 'email';
  public const RULE_MIN = 'min';
  public const RULE_MAX = 'max';
  public const RULE_MATCH = 'match';
  
  /*the purpouse of this function is load data to the object, when i save the data this way it works well*/

  public function loadData($data){
  foreach($data as $key => $value){
      if (property_exists($this, $key)){
        $this->{$key} = $value;
      }
    };
  }
```

/*here is the function that is giving troubles to me*/

public function validate(){

```
    foreach ($this->rules() as $attibute => $rules) {
      // code...
      $value = $this->{$attibute};
      foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        // code...
          $ruleName = $rule;
          if (!is_string($ruleName)) {
            // code...
            $ruleName = $rule[0];
          }
          if ($ruleName == self::RULE_REQUIRED && !$value){
               $this->addError($attribute, self::RULE_REQUIRED);
          }

      }
    }
  }
```

this is the child class

```
namespace app\models;
use app\core\Model;
class RegisterModel extends Model
{
  public string $firstname;
  public string $lastname;
  public string $email;
  public string $password;
  public string $confirmPassword;
  /*los nombres tienen que coincidir con los deldocumento register.php*/
  public function register(){
    return true;
  }
  public function rules(): array{
    return [
        'firstname'=> [self::RULE_REQUIRED],
        'lastname'=> [self::RULE_REQUIRED],
        'email'=> [self::RULE_REQUIRED, self::RULE_EMAIL],
        'password'=> [self::RULE_REQUIRED, [self::RULE_MIN, 'min'=>8], [self::RULE_MAX, 'max'=>24]],
        'password'=> [self::RULE_REQUIRED, [self::RULE_MATCH, 'match'=>'password']]
    ];
  }

}
```

when i create a instance (lets call it ChildInstance) of the class and load the information of $firstname,  $lastname, $email, $password, $confirmpasword and then use var_dump on ChildInstance I can see the information i load on this instance. but when i use the function validate (both functions validate and loadData belongs to the parent class) it raise this error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Typed property app\models\RegisterModel::$firstname must not be accessed before initialization
```

I already solved this problem by using inheritance, but I can't solve it using this aproach, why the information stored cannot be accesed using a function of the parent class? thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am suddenly getting a "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error when introducing properties type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265625/why-i-am-suddenly-getting-a-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initiali)

Comment: hello ron, it doesn't, i can acces to variables between the class, my problem is that i can't use variables of the child using functions of the father

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the typed properties, i.e. `public string $firstname`.

When you define the type for a property, but don't give it a default value, it has an `uninitialized` state under the PHP hood. This error is essentially saying: you have tried to access a typed property before you have given it a value.

Borrowing an example from [madewithlove](https://madewithlove.com/blog/software-engineering/typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization/), this will cause the same error:

```php
class User
{
    private int $id;
    private string $username;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}

$user = new User(1);
echo $user->getUsername();
```

Notice we never gave `$username` a value, nor does it have a default set on the property.

I'm not sure what the best solution would be; it depends on what your shared `Model` is designed to do, how child instances are instantiated, etc. Setting default property values is one option. Instantiating models and property values via reflection may be another.

Comment: but the function loadData isloading the data to the child class, i also test that using var_dump

Comment: I first give the value tothe child object and then try to use it using the validate function, and is at that moment that raises error

Comment: I assume that your `loadData` phase is not going as you expect, then. I can clearly reproduce the problem using your code, and having `loadData` skip certain properties. Inheritance is not an issue - focus on the typed properties and how their values are being populated. Check for misspellings or changes in capitalization - the keys passed to `loadData` should match the model properties exactly.