# Symfony 5 - PHP 7.4 - Should I initialize all my nullable properties to null?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, php-7.4

On my symfony 5 project, I am in the process of migrating from PHP 7.3 to 7.4.

Now I can type all my properties.

In my Entities files, PhpStorm automatically typed all my properties for me, but I very often end up with this kind of error :

> Typed property App\Entity\User::$name must not be accessed before
> initialization

I have looked through several sites that talk about this problem, like:

[Why I am suddenly getting a "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error when introducing properties type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265625/why-i-am-suddenly-getting-a-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initiali)

https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7944

But I don't have a real answer on what I really need to do, some people seem to contradict each other.

So if I understand correctly, I had to go from :

```
private ?string $name;
```

to

```
private ?string $name = null;
```

And the same for all the $id properties, I should put :

```
private ?int $id = null;
```

It's correct ?

Now, should I reproduce this system for absolutely all of my properties which are nullable?

But that's not all, I also have properties which are not supposed to be nullable, but which the setters and getters still offered this possibility.

And **PhpStorm** automatically types these properties to me as nullable. Should I also initialize them with a null value?

For **DateTime**? I initialize them to **null value** too?

**Relations between Entities?**

And finally, the **collections**? Before I used **ArrayCollection**, and now I have to type them with **Collection**, like this :

```
private Collection $absences;
```

But before that, in the constructor, I had this:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->absences = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Should I keep this?

Thank you very much for all of your responses !

Comment: [Related.](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7944)

Comment: This is precisely the link that I checked before posting, but I did not really understand the conclusion

Comment: The conclusion is exactly as what it says in the linked duplicate. If you have typed properties, you should make sure that that the **values** of the properties match the declared types. Either you set a **valid** value on construction, or you initialize the property with a **valid** value. If you leave it uninitialized, it will fail as the error shows.

Comment: I edited my first post in more detail because I don't think it is a post duplication. I also posted this message on Reddit as you advised me Cerad

Comment: Okay, I understand a little better. But what about collections, as I explained in my first post (which I edited)?

Comment: For Doctrine collections you usually initialize as `new ArrayCollection() ` on the constructor. It's still a dupe. You need to initialize properties to a value of the correct type before accessing them.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor