# Proper handling of required fields during entity update in Symfony Forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Let's say I have simple entity `Foo` with required text field `bar`.

```
namespace App\Entity;

class Foo 
{
    protected string $bar;

    public function getBar(): string
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }

    public function setBar(string $bar): void
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

To manage this entity I use Symfony Forms and `FooType` class

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('bar', TextType::class, ['required' => true]);
    }
}
```

... and corresponding `FooController`

```
class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    public function update(Request $request, FooRepository $fooRepository, int $id): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(FooType::class, $fooRepository->find($id));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

With such config, frontend validation prevents submitting empty value in `bar` field, and this is good.

However, when somebody bypass frontend validation (e.g. by providing whitespace sign), the code crashes during `handleRequest` with following message:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "bar"." at /srv/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php line 211

The error is obviously caused by type hint in `setBar(string $bar)`, where Symfony tries to provide `null` (whitespace is trimmed to empty string, and then empty string is parsed to `null`).

I'm wondering, what is the proper way of handling this kind of situations with Symfony Forms. I was searching for possible solutions, but none of them seems to be satisfying:

- changing type hint in `setBar` to `?string` isn't valid, because the `bar` field in my domain should never be null
- simply adding `'empty_data' => ''` causes that `$form->isValid()` returns `true`, and the entity is saved with empty string value, which is obviously not expected result (that's why I marked it as required)
- adding `'constraints' => [new NotBlank()]` doesn't help, as it still tries to `setBar(null)`, and makes app crashing

The only working solution seems to be using the combination of `empty_data` and `NotBlank` constraint, as proposed here [Symfony 5 - Forms and Entities - NotBlank constraint with not nullable string entity attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772645/symfony-5-forms-and-entities-notblank-constraint-with-not-nullable-string-en)

```
$builder->add('bar', TextType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'empty_data' => '',
    'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
];
```

But adding this every time I simply need to have `required` field, looks like a big overhead, so I was thinking there should be some better way to do it. I could probably override `FormBuilder` to automatically add `empty_data` and `NotBlank` every time I set `required` field, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel.

What's even more interesting, it seems to be a problem only with updating existing models - creating new ones (accidentally?) works, because the condition `$propertyValue !== $this->getPropertyValue($data, $propertyPath)` in `PropertyPathAccessor` is false (`null !== null` is `false`), and it skips calling `setBar` with `null` value.

**Do I miss something? Or is it the way how Symfony works? (imho possible bug)**

Comment: It would be best if you used constraints on your entity classes. If I remember correctly, `required` is only used for rendering the required attribute on the HTML form element and doesn't affect the actual validation.

Comment: @pmatsumura This might work, however it will still require adding `empty_data` everywhere, right? I'm really surprised, that marking field as `required` doesn't affect the validation, but you're right - it's stated also in the docs: `This is superficial and independent of validation.`