# $env must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: symfony

I upgrade my project from SF 5.4 to SF 6 with php 8.1.2.

With my dev env I have no errors!

When I use the prod env when I cache clear I have the error:

```
In Route.php line 196:
                                                                                                              
  Typed property Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::$env must not be accessed before initialization
```

I try to remove the var/cache folder.

Do you have any ideas how to fix that one?

I found the same error in stack and I replace the handler_id with null value.

The error come from the SF router vendor. Route.php is not my own code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why I am suddenly getting a "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error when introducing properties type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265625/why-i-am-suddenly-getting-a-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initiali)

Comment: I know the error .... I don't know why I get that one in a SF vendor. This IS NOT a duplicate

Comment: Print `$env` in your development environment and see which value it has. Then try to determine why it is unset in your production environment. See https://madewithlove.com/blog/software-engineering/typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization/

Comment: I guess you ever tried to rm -rf your vendor and run composer install again

Comment: I tried to remove and reinstall the vendors :)

Comment: I had the same error on PHP 8.0.10 while upgrading 5.4 to 6.0. cache:clear always threw that error. After upgrading recipes and manually removing cache folder, cache:clear was [OK]. Also see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/45802

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same issue so I cleared cache typing this command `symfony console cache:clear` to make all work again.
You can also refer to this link if the need arises:
[$env not initialized](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/45802#issuecomment-1076097966)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: nice - worked - thanks for the hint +1

Comment: @Corepex can you explain how this worked for you?? The problem in the question is that the error occurs when running cache:clear, and you solved it by running cache:clear?