# Symfony / PHPUnit Test: "$variable must not be accessed before initialization"

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

**I try to get the kernel root dir in setUp method of unitTest:**

```
private string $databaseDirPath;

protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    self::bootKernel();
    $container = static::getContainer();
    $this->databaseDirPath = $container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/resources/database/' ;

}
/**
 * @dataProvider provideInexistentFile
 */
public function testConvertReturnNull(string $file):void
{
    if (!file_exists($file) || !is_readable($file)) {
        $response = null;
    }

    $this->assertNull($response);
}

public function provideInexistentFile(): array 
{
    return [
        'inexistent file' => [
            $this->databaseDirPath. 'comdfsasd.csv',
        ],
        'inexistent file' => [
            $this->databaseDirPath. 'gbfdgbzsa.csv',
        ],
    ];
}
```

**and this the error:**

> $databaseDirPath must not be accessed before initialization

Answer (score 0):

Your type-hint for the `$databaseDirPath` property is incorrect.

The `setUp` method is not a constructor.

The variable is initialized as `null` which the type-hint doesn't allow.

Use the following:

```php
private ?string $dateBaseDirPath = null;
```

Further information can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59265626/1832745).

Comment: Changing the type-hint does not fix the problem, because data providers are run before `setUp`.

Answer (score 0):

Data providers are invoked **before** any hooks like `setUp` or `beforeClass` are executed. So although @Nicolai might be technically correct, with saying your type-hint is incorrect, that's not the root of the issue.

But you could simply add the "data-fetching" to your data provider:

```php
public function provideInexistentFile(): array 
{
    self::bootKernel();
    $container = static::getContainer();
    $databaseDirPath = $container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/resources/database/';

    return [
        'inexistent file' => [
            $databaseDirPath. 'comdfsasd.csv',
        ],
        'inexistent file' => [
            $databaseDirPath. 'gbfdgbzsa.csv',
        ],
    ];
}
```