# Typed property must not be accessed before initialization during User signup

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am getting this error while signing up on my website in production. The error appears only on production, on localhost there is no error.

> Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization

[image: Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization]

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am suddenly getting a "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error when introducing properties type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265625/why-i-am-suddenly-getting-a-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initiali)

Comment: Thanks so Much for your answer  the issue has been solved by changed the php version  it stucked because of php version it was 8.1 and there is some packages need to be downgrade for the version