# Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization while creating pdf in shared hosting server

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, dompdf

I am running a php laravel program with laravel v 10 and php 8.1.2 which is supposed to create a pdf document.
I have no problem when running the program in localhost but I am getting this issue after the system is hosted in shared hosting with a cPanel.

```
protected function passedValidation()
{
       Pdf::loadView('quotation.quotationpdf', [

            'taxes' => $this->taxes,

            'force_majuere' => $this->force_majuere,

        ])->save(storage_path('app/public/quotations/quotation.pdf'));
}
```

This is my code and error is being shown in `'force_majuere' => $this->force_majuere,` this line.

I have searched the internet and my problem is close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74137683/typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization-during-user-signup) but there is no answers or solution provided. Some other solutions I have found are to upgrade php to 8.2 but it is not possible as php 8.2 is not supported by my server.
I have tested my program in php 8.1.2 and php 8.2 in local environment but my remote server is using php 8.1.21 could this be the issue, or issue lies in laravel-dompdf which I am using version 2.0.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am suddenly getting a "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error when introducing properties type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265625/why-i-am-suddenly-getting-a-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initiali)

Comment: @Tobias I am aware with this thread and it addresses the change made in php 7.4 but it doesn't solve my problem. I believe my problem has something to do with php 8.1 version of cPanel or dompdf 2.0.1.

Comment: Can you show the definition for `$this->force_majuere`? And do you modify it at all in the `__construct()` method?

Comment: @aynber error has nothing to do with `$this->force_majuere`, as I have few other pages which makes pdf and they too throws same error on the last line of the array of second argument of `Pdf::loadView()` function

Comment: Can you provide the full error & trace?

Comment: @aynber https://flareapp.io/share/17xDV8L7

Comment: Darn, that doesn't help much. If you remove that line, does it work, or does the error move to the previous line?

Comment: @aynber if I remove that line of code it moves to previous line.